# gulp task with a parameter and callback

Tags: asynchronous, gulp

I'd like to add a parameter to a gulp task that is already using a callback function to indicate when tasks are completed, is there any way to do this?

Current:

```
gulp.task('build', build);

function build(done) {
    // do stuff here
    done();
}
```

Desired:

```
gulp.task('buildA', build(optionsA));
gulp.task('buildB', build(optionsB)); 

function build(options, done) {
     // do stuff here with params
     done();
}
```

This gives an error of 'done is undefined'.

Comment: What about a closure? A functions that receive options and return a function that return the task function?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.. so I would have a buildA(done) and buildB(done) function that call build passing in the correct parameters and the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few ways to do this:

First, make a closure a invoke before like this:

```
gulp.task('buildA', build(optionsA));
gulp.task('buildB', build(optionsB)); 

function build(options) {
    return function (done) {
        // do stuff here with params
        done();
    }    
}
```

Second, bind your current functions with the options desired:

```
gulp.task('buildA', build.bind(null, optionsA));
gulp.task('buildB', build.bind(null, optionsB)); 

function build(options, done) {
     // do stuff here with params
     done();
}
```